# Enhanced RegEx for turning URLs to links

Tags: php, regex

Ok I know that there are a lot of ways to turn a URL into a link (anchor tag)...

The thing is I want to match a URL which supports http and https protocol... it will then open in a new tab... but I'm looking for a SECURE way of doing this... so the simple `(.*)` doesn't do the work.... I have tried something like this:

> ```
>     $var=preg_replace('#(https?://([_a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.[a-z0-9]+)/?[^ ()<>]*)#i', '< href="\\1" target="blank">\\1</a>', $var);
> ```

BUT if I have a string like this: "Hey check out this "http://google.com" man" ... it turns it into something like this

> Hey check out this:
>   `<a href="http://google.com&quot;" target="blank">http://google.com&quot;</a>`

so I end up with having a double quote at the end of the link :S any idea how to enhance this RegEx? I tryed adding a `"` in the "not allowed characters":  `[^ "()<>]` but it has no effect at all.

Comment: no use :( still the same...

Comment: actually now it doesn't work at all :D

Comment: What is your desired output?

Comment: it should output <a href="URL" target="_blank">URL</a> :) very simple but the pattern I gave above matches double quotes ... I just want that it doesn't match them :) thats all :D

Comment: Being perfect is impossible. As it is fundamentally ambiguous. Both `http://www.google.com?xx="` and `http://www.google.com?xx=` are legal links.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to disallow the word `&quot;` in your regex, not only the character `"`

The only way I know to disallow words is there : [Regular expression to match a line that doesn't contain a word?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/406230/regular-expression-to-match-string-not-containing-a-word)

So I guess this regex may work :

```
#(https?://([_a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.[a-z0-9]+)/?((?!(&quot;|\(|\)|<|>)).)*)#i
```

Comment: Works like a charm! :) thanks... I was trying to add &quot; the first place but like a sign not like a word :) I'll do a bit more testing now...